# TabviewPager fragement id is not found if version is below 17

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I created a Tabviewpager with fragments in it.I am passing getchildfragmentmanager so that when navigating back , tabviewpager fragment appears.At the time of clicking on an listitem :(listview fragment is one of the fragment of ViewPager)

1. It goes to next tab fragment ( when android version is equal to or above 17)
   ( i am using V13 and V7 libraries here)
2. App Crashes saying it does not find container id for a fragment.
   (To support older versions i am using v4 and v7)

Can anyone tell why same code is crashing the app in second sceneraio?

Here are the logs :

> 03-01 09:41:55.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5393): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-01 09:41:55.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5393): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f080055 (com.tapplent.catalog:id/container) for fragment ViewFragment{5366ff94 #3 id=0x7f080055 view}
>   03-01 09:41:55.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5393):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:939)
>   03-01 09:41:55.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5393):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
>   03-01 09:41:55.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5393):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
>   03-01 09:41:55.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5393):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
>   03-01 09:41:55.328: E/AndroidRuntime(5393):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:454)

Comment: Post your code and your logcat

Comment: Hi, edited the question.Please check.

Comment: Your view is not in the layout.